# How can i handle and limit the number of the query executed on the laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

How to visualize number of the queries that are executed and ways to minimizing those queries so as to improve the system performance

Comment: I need some clarification. Do you want to limit the number of queries or the number of results?

Comment: Most of the times the queries can be best check with you MySQL/MSSQL/... troubleshooting tools.

Comment: I want to limit number of the queries sent to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which queries are sent to your db, you can use these two solutions :

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#listening-for-query-events
- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

If you are looking for what does impact your performances, you can use these two instructions to target the right lines of your code :

```
$time = microtime(true); // we save the precise time in milliseconds
// some lines of code
dd(microtime(true) - $time); // prints the milliseconds spent since $time was saved
```

Let me know if it helped !

Comment: Thanks, **laravel-debugba** worked fine... I can now visualize the queries that are executed when the page renders of certain events is triggered which communicate with database.. Am still figuring out how to reduce number of queries

Comment: Do you need something else or it fully answer your question ?